# How to start urxvt with tmux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux, urxvt

I want to run tmux when I open urxvt terminal, I found somewhat functional solution;

`[[ $TERM = "xterm" ]] && { tmux && exit 0; }` *in .bashrc

But replacing `"xterm"` with `"urxvt"` or `"urxvt-256color"` doesn't work, so I'm just using `{ tmux && exit 0; }`.

But I get this "error":

`sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`

I did some quick searching and it probably isn't good, so here I am asking for a proper way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_on_every_shell_login

If not running interactively, do not do anything. Else check that terminal begins with urxvt and TMUX variable is null. Only then execute tmux.

```
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then
        return
elif [[  $TERM == urxvt* && -z "$TMUX" ]]; then
        exec tmux && exit 0;
fi
```

Also, I realised I made a mistake using quotes around urxvt* previously. The wildcard * will only work in the test without the quotes.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This does work but it still throws the same error

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try again.